# How to use isset in if return variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have some condition if request isset or no and retun in view blade laravel like this:

```
$compare1 = $request->compare1;
$compare2 = $request->compare2;

if (isset($compare1)) {
    $laptop1 = Laptop::where('slug', $compare1)->firstOrFail();
    return view('compare.index', ['laptop1' => $laptop1->id]);
  } elseif(isset($compare2)) {
    $laptop2 = Laptop::where('slug', $compare2)->firstOrFail();
    return view('compare.index', ['laptop1' => $laptop1->id, 'laptop2' => $laptop2->id]);
  }elseif(isset($compare1, $compare)) {
    $laptop1 = Laptop::where('slug', $compare1)->firstOrFail();
    $laptop2 = Laptop::where('slug', $compare2)->firstOrFail();
    return view('compare.index', ['laptop1' => $laptop1->id, 'laptop2' => $laptop2->id]);
  }else {
    return view('compare.index');
  }
```

if isset($compare1, $compare) run, $laptop2 not found, any solution for this case...?
Thanks before

Comment: `elseif(isset($compare1, $compare)` would never run anyways because if either of the values were set your code would never check that elseif. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i expect if isset($compare1, $compare) return 2 value: $laptop1 and $laptop2

Comment: you mean `$compare1` and `$compare2` ?

Comment: if only isset($compare1) return $laptop1.
if only isset($compare2) return $laptop2.
if both isset($compare1, $compare) return $laptop and  $laptop2.
if no request, not pass var $laptop1 and $laptop2

Comment: should i use switch case to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you have is incorrect. Currently, your code `elseif(isset($compare1, $compare))` will never execute because if either `$compare1` or `$compare2` are set, your `if` statement will already exit before it gets to the 3rd one. You also have a lot of redundant code (repeating a line of code depending on which `if` block is executed) which is easily reduced to fewer lines and cleaner code.

### Simple Approach

Consider this; (You should be able to replace your entire `if` block with this)

```
//set up an empty array to return
$return = [];

//check if `$compare1` is set, and add to return array if it is
if(isset($compare1)) {
    $return['laptop1'] = (Laptop::where('slug', $compare1)->firstOrFail())->id;
}

//same as above but for `$compare2`
if(isset($compare2)) {
    $return['laptop2'] = (Laptop::where('slug', $compare2)->firstOrFail())->id;
}

return view('compare.index', $return);
```

---

### Dynamic Approach

This may be a little bit overkill if you are just doing 2 comparisons but it definitely has some upsides.

- Similar amount of code as the simple approach
- No need to define separate variables for every comparison (e.g `$compare1 = $request->compare1;`, etc)
- Easily add more comparisons to your return by simply adding them to the `$comparisons` array
- Future Proof

Code:

```
//empty array to return
$return = [];

//list of variables to compare
$comparisons = ['compare1', 'compare2'];

//loop through each comparison
foreach($comparisons as $key => $request_object) {

    $count = $key + 1; //keys start at 0, so we add 1 to make it count sequentially 1,2,3 ...
    $comparison = $request->{$request_object}; //grab your comparison object

    //check if comparison object is set, add it to return array if it is
    if(isset($comparison)) {
        $return["laptop{$count}"] = (Laptop::where('slug', $comparison)->firstOrFail())->id;
    }
}

return view('compare.index', $return);
```

Comment: the second argument to `view` defaults to `[]` anyway so pass it in :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be better to split code in parts to improve code quality.

Some thoughts after analyze your code:

- Always returns `view('compare.index')`
- Laravel Request contains a `has` method
- Multiple conditional concatenation using if elseif.. (it decrease legibility)
- It's more logical to pass the complete model to view instead of only id. 
  Otherwise, rename var to `laptop1Id` or similar
- Take care of code duplication

#### Proposal

```
if($request->has('compare1')) {
    $laptop1 = Laptop::where('slug', $request->get('compare1'))->firstOrFail();
}

if($request->has('compare2')) {
    $laptop2 = Laptop::where('slug', $request->get('compare2'))->firstOrFail();
}

return view('compare.index', compact('laptop1', 'laptop2'));
```

If find/search a `Laptop` is a domain rule, you could encapsulate it in a method/scope in model, querying like:

`$laptop = Laptop::findOrFailBySlug($val);`

`$laptop = Laptop::slug($val)->firstOrFail();`

Comment: Note that starting from PHP 7.3, `compact` will return Undefined Index errors for undefined variables: https://3v4l.org/eVGtf